# NPM install java

Tags: java, node.js, npm

I have a problem with installing java using npm:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: build/binding.sln
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\sienikam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
```

Does anybody have a similar problem and found a solution?

I want to run a script which uses the `webdriver-sync` library.
But I get the following error:

> module.js:672 return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
>   Error: The specified module could not be found.
>   \?\C:\Users\sienikam\node_modules\java\build\Release\nodejavabridge_bindings.node

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I incorporated your comment into the question.